# Reporting error string from controller to the angular client

Tags: c#, angular, controller

I have a controller method from which I would like to return to my angular client some error condition when `account` object is null. I used exception below and it works, but is there a better way of reporting error string to the angular client then the below one.

```
[Authorize]
[HttpPost("get-schedule-from-pool/{id}")]
public ActionResult<AccountResponse> GetScheduleFromPool(int id, UpdateScheduleRequest scheduleReq)
{
    // users can update their own account and admins can update any account
    if (id != Account.Id && Account.Role != Role.Admin)
        return Unauthorized(new { message = "Unauthorized" });

    var account = _accountService.GetScheduleFromPool(id, scheduleReq);
    if(account == null)
    {
        // Request.Body.
        // return HttpError("Function :" + scheduleReq.UserFunction + " for date: " + scheduleReq.Date + " already taken");
        
        throw new Exception("Sample exception.");
    }
    
    return Ok(account);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return a error message or error code to the client there's a few ways to do it.
Using [StatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.statuscodes?view=aspnetcore-6.0):

```
return  StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError,"Details");
```

or

```
return StatusCode(500,"Details")
```

Or using the default [wrappers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase?view=aspnetcore-6.0#methods):

```
return Problem("Details");
```

[Here](https://umbraco.com/knowledge-base/http-status-codes/) a list of all error codes and what they mean.

Comment: I have tested `return StatusCode(500,"Details")` but the `Details` message is not available in error reactive handler `error: error => {}`. Error just displays `Internal Server Error`.

Comment: Try looking at the response json, it should bee in the response body

Comment: I have only access to error variable in an angular reactive error handler.

Comment: Sorry I can only help you with c#, try you're api using post man or swagger. Or in you're browser you can inspect element and go to "Network" tab and see the request and the response there. https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/